# How to gererate a single pulse depending on a state machne in C?

Tags: c, logic, pulse

I want to write a c code to generate a pulse but cant seem to wrap my head around the logic to implement it. I come from a strong Verilog background & know how to do this in verilog(look for a change of state using xor & use that pulse, stretch it over time if needed by registering it multiple times)

How should I do this in C? I want to do something like

```
while(1)
{
   switch(state)
   case 0: // generate single pulse
   case 1: // dont generate 
   case 2: // dont gererate
   case 3: // generate single pulse
   usleep(1000) // I want a 1ms pulse
}
```

state is modified by a code running on FPGA, so it changes depending on some logic.
Cant seem to thing of a way to do that. Some guidance will be appreciated

Comment: "*pulse*" in which sense? What kind of "*pulse*". What do want to pulse?

Comment: You could switch high in one loop then switch low in next, e.g. by using a state 4 "pulsing".

Comment: Single Pulse as in a signal which is default low but when some condition occurs goes high & low with high time = say 1ms

Comment: @Yunnosch I tried something like "if(signal=0) signal =1; else signal = 0" but that will generate multiple pulses as long as that state is stable

Comment: You need to provide more context. With the code you have shown, something like "entry action" is not possible. Please try to give something closer to a [mcve]. A step towards a suitable powerful state machine would be to maintain a "statebefore" variable.

Comment: Would it be a problem if the state machine is "blind" for events while waiting the desired 1ms?

Comment: @Yunnosch AFAIK usleep blocks so, the next loop & state machine is executed after 1 ms only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149881/discussion-between-yunnosch-and-kharobangdo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a slightly more powerful statemachine, which can do entry-actions.

Assuming

- it is Ok for the state machine to be blind while pulsing
- variable `state` changes inside your loop (e.g. being volatile and updated from ISR perhaps)
- or state is updated somehow inside the loop (pseudo code for that is present)

You indicated in chat that you have some control over when the variable `state` changes. That is important. Either use the polling function `updatestate()`, which is called from a pseudo code line; or somehow make sure that the variable does not change between `// enter protection ...` and `// leave protection ...`.
However, the statemachine will still be blind for changes between, especially during the `usleep(1000);`. If that is a problem, you need noticably more complex mechanisms.

Pseudo code proposal:

```
// somewhere before
volatile int state = 0; // somehow changing within the loop 

int statecopy = 0;  
int statebefore = state,

while(1)
{
    // updatestate(); // if that is necessary

    // Note that the state machine is blind for changes to state
    // between executions of these initial lines.
    // I.e. changes are noticed only when executing the update above
    // or the critical section below this comment. (depending on how
    // the variable state changes.

    // enter protection for critical section
    statebefore = statecopy;
    statecopy   = state;
    // leave protection for critical section

    switch(statecopy )
    {
        case 0: // generate single pulse
            if (statecopy != statebefore)
            {
                // switch high
                usleep(1000); // I want a 1ms pulse
                // switch low
            }
            break;
        case 1: // dont generate 
            break;
        case 2: // dont gererate
            break;
        case 3: // generate single pulse
            if (statecopy != statebefore)
            {
                // switch high
                usleep(1000); // I want a 1ms pulse
                // switch low
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to implement little logic for state changing and action for each state, like this:

```
int state = 0;
while(1) {
  switch(state) {
    case 0: // generate single pulse
       start_pulse();
       usleep(1000);
       stop_pulse();
       break;
    case 1: // dont generate , wait 1ms?
       usleep(1000);
       break;
    case 2: // dont generate, wait 1ms?
       usleep(1000);
       break;
    case 3: // generate single pulse
       start_pulse();
       usleep(1000);
       stop_pulse();
       break;
  }
  state = (state+1)%3; // next state: 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2,...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the switch examples

```
switch( state ) {
case 1:
case 2:
  usleep(1000);
  break;
case 0:
case 3:
  /* pulse high */
  usleep(1000);
  /* pulse low */
}
```

More is possible but probably not worth is, let the compiler figure it out.